# How do you identify the base & perpendicular of a right angled triangle.

Tags: triangles

It is easier to tell with this diagram [image]

But what about this one ? For triangle BDC.

[image]

Here , how do you tell either BD or DC is base ?

Comment: You cannot, based *just* on the image. Any of those may be considered "a base". If it appears in a question, the rest of the question should provide necessary context. If it doesn't, then the question is ambiguous and needs to be returned to its source, to be clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any side of a triangle (right or not) can be its base. It is something you choose, so choose whatever is most convenient for your calculation. Once you've chosen a base, the *height* of the triangle is the distance from the base to the opposite vertex.

For example, to calculate the area of this triangle

[image]

We could take

- $AC$ as base, which has length $4$. The height is the distance from the line $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ to $B$, which is $3$ (since $\angle A$ is a right angle). Therefore the area is $\frac 12(4)(3) = 6$.
- $AB$ as base, which has length $3$. The height is the distance to $C$, which is $4$. So the area is $\frac12(3)(4) = 6$.
- $BC$ as base, which has length $5$. The height is the distance to $A$, which is $2.4$. So the area is $\frac12(5)(2.4) = 6$.

No matter which side we choose as base, the area calculated is the same.

Comment: Thnx a lot. It solves a lot of my problems.